# Почему я не могу получить размер inputStream?

Tags: java, android

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{MainActivity.jsonObject.getString("one"), MainActivity.jsonObject.getString("two"),MainActivity.jsonObject.getString("skype0")});
        p.waitFor();

        InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
        int length = inputStream.available();

        Log.e("asd",length+" ");
```

Размер 0 показывает

Comment: А что, собственно, за комманда запускается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `InputStream` так устроен, что он может читать из источника неизвестного размера. В данном случае источник — это вывод результатов выполнения другой программы. Другая программа же не говорит в самом начале, сколько байт она выдаст в стандартный поток вывода. Было бы очень неудобно программировать, если бы вам в начале выполнения программы требовалось сразу сообщить, сколько вы собрались байт вывести в стандартный поток вывода.

Для того, чтобы узнать сколько там байт, надо просто всё считать, пока оно не закончится. Тогда оно всё будет в памяти. Всё вычитать без сторонних библиотек можно, например, таким методом:

```
public static byte[] readAllBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte [BUFFER_SIZE];
    int len;

    while( (len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1 )
    {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

(Такой метод реализован в разных библиотеках. Например, в Apache Commons IO есть `IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream)`).

Тогда вы можете спокойно сделать

```
byte[] data = p.getInputStream();
int length = data.length;
```